# Как установить footer в нижнюю часть страницы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть сайт, на котором мне нужно установить footer в низ страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код css:

```
footer{
    background-color: var(--footer_c);
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#footer{
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#footer > div{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

#footer > div > a {
    position: relative;
}

.link{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    right: 45px;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Для понимания "какой тебе нужен" футер нужно привести пример своей верстки "рамы" страницы... Если нужен блок, который просто всегда будет "висеть внизу" - может устроить и `position: fixed;`. Но есть и иные варианты реализации футера.

Comment: Position fixed же вроде его просто заставит следить за скролом, оставляя на своём месте. Мне же нужно просто, чтобы этот блок был ниже, чем блок с проектами

Comment: Потому и писал ранее что от тебя нужен пример (минимальный) твоей "рамы" страницы. На этом примере можно будет показать варианты решения. В противном случае ты так и будешь фыркать что тебе не подходит очередной вариант футера... :)

Comment: Вот тебе "онлайн-конструктор" для "рамы" страницы http://createtemplate.hellohtml.ru

Answer (score 0):

```
footer { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Вот

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Думаю, вы не так поняли. Мне не нужно, чтобы футер следил за скролом. Мне нужно, чтобы он просто был в нижней части страницы и шёл после блока с карточками

Comment: @ALitesLite float?